# Android TabContent Change

Tags: android, tabs, tabwidget

[image: layout]

Hello,

In the following picture I have the layout of my app.  I have a tab widget within a tab host at the bottom (Green Color).  I have the tabcontent in the middle (Pink Color).

I have 3 different tabs in the tab host however, I have 2 buttons on the top-right (Blue Color).  I want to click on a button at the top and have the tab content change.

Is this possible?

On a regular tab click I have each tab open different activities.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `yourTabHost.setCurrenttab(INDEX YOU WANT TO SET)`

Comment: how would this solve anything? Only the 3 green tabs at the bottom are part of the Tab Widget. The two blue buttons on the top are not part of the Tab Widget.

Comment: dude in the onClick of the two blue buttons you can use this statement.

Comment: that could work but I don't want to go to one of the tabs. I want to open a new activity within the tabcontent.